# Ionic 4 app won't run on IOS 10.3.3 or lower

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework, ipad, ionic4

I have 2 ipads I am trying to deploy an Ionic 4 app onto. One with IOS 10.3.3 and the other with 9.3.5. Both are giving me the same error when I try to run them in Xcode.

I have set the DEPLOYMENT_TARGET in Xcode to 9.3 for them. I have also tried downgrading Cordova-plugin-ionic-webview down to version 1.2.0 in the ionic app and still got the same error. I have also tried creating a brand new empty Ionic v4 app just to make sure it didn't have to do with any of my plugins and I still got the same error.

[This is the error that Xcode is giving me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XolFV.png)

Comment: can you please share more information?

Comment: What information would you like to see?